# Authentication without user credentials

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, authentication

I'm putting together a personal React site and want to send requests to an AWS API Gateway. However, I just want *my site* to be able to pull data. There will be no user model and every auth model I've ever used requires the user to do something with sign-in, be it user/pwd or AD. Can someone guide me to a model that covers this scenario?

Comment: So you want just your React app to access the API?

Comment: @NathanHeffley yessir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common approach is to use a Cognito Identity Pool with "Unauthenticated Identities" enabled.  You can secure your API gateway endpoints using IAM, and require requests to be [sig4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) signed.

With this approach, Cognito is used only in a kind identity broker capacity, not as an actual identity provider.  You do not need to create a User Pool or use any other identity management features of Cognito.  In this capacity, Cognito is essentially just a thin layer between your code and the [underlying STS APIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) that produce the IAM keys your application needs.

Using the Cognito SDK, you request [temporary IAM credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) (access key, secret key, session token) that can be used to sign the requests.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005217/how-to-make-unauthenticated-access-working-with-amazon-cognito/46749416#46749416) outlines one way to accomplish this.  When the protected AWS resource you want to access is API Gateway, your code may look something like the example near the end of [this post](https://jonascheng.github.io/aws/2016/05/19/cognito-with-unauthenticated-identities/).

I typically either use [aws-api-gateway-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client), as the example does, or [aws4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4) with axios to sign requests.

As noted in the linked to answer above, I normally use `AWS.config.credentials.get()`, rather than `AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()` to actually get the IAM keys ([as in this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html)).

The signed requests then include an Authorization header that is very difficult to counterfeit. I don't want to suggest that this approach is bulletproof, but it does at least give you a *reasonable* level of confidence that your API Gateway endpoints are only being successfully invoked by your application.

Comment: This...is quite the answer. I’ll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this solves my issue. YatrixApp should be authenticated, but MikePatrickApp shouldn't be. I don't see where that's possible with your answer. Did I just misunderstand? **Using the Cognito SDK, you request temporary IAM credentials (access key, secret key, session token) that can be used to sign the requests.** seems to be that part, but it I don't see how there's determination between two disparate apps.

Comment: The semantics around _Authenticated_ and _Unauthenticated_ get a little confusing here, but I *think* I get what you're saying.  Ostensibly, YatrixApp would know your identity pool id, and contain logic to use it to get IAM keys and sign requests with them.  OtherApp wouldn't.  Therefore requests from OtherApp would fail, while those from YatrixApp would succeed.  Could OtherApp compromise your identity pool id and add the appropriate .js to abuse your API?  It probably _could_, but they'd have to be very determined attackers.  Thus "not bulletproof" and "_reasonable_ level of confidence"

Comment: Your question and comment inspired me to post the natural follow up question.  Happy hacking!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170717/aws-cognito-how-sensitive-is-my-identity-pool-id